# ComponentWillMount renders again after onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When you load the page `ComponentWillMount` triggers `getLocalStorage` function. This has several checks and triggers the `search` function. When you load the page it is trying to retrieve the query from localStorage. When you change the input(which changes the query) and submit, the `search` function should trigger but does not fetch.. instead it refreshes the page and load componentDidMount again? Then after the refresh it works perfectly. Why is it only refreshing one time?

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.getLocalStorage();
};

getLocalStorage = () => {
    //Check if localstorage is supported by browser
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

        //Check if localstorage item query is defined
        if (localStorage.getItem("query") !== null) {

            //Set query to localstorage item and go to search function
            //This works and triggers the search function
            this.setState({
                query: localStorage.getItem("query")
            },() => {
                this.search();
            });
        }

        // If localstorage item is not defined go to location
        else{
            this.getLocation();
        }
    }

    // If localstorage is not supported by the browser go to location
    else {
        this.getLocation();
    }
};
```

When you click on the button it triggers the search function but does not fetch. Instead it trigger componentDidMount again?

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Find your location..."/>
<button onClick={this.search}>Submit</button>
```

Search function

```
search = () => {

    this.setState({
        secondLoader:true
    });

    let BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
    let ACCES_TOKEN = "token";
    let FETCH_URL = `${BASE_URL}address=${this.state.query}&key=${ACCES_TOKEN}`;

    alert('the search function does not fetch like below instead it trigger componentDidMount again');


    fetch(FETCH_URL, {
        method: "GET"

    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            //If repsonse got zero results use amsterdam location
            if(json.status === 'ZERO_RESULTS'){
                this.setState({
                    query: 'Amsterdam'
                });
            }

            //Otherwise use query
            else {
                const geocode = json.results[0].geometry.location;

                this.setState({
                    latitude: geocode.lat,
                    longitude: geocode.lng
                });
            }

            const BASE_URL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
            const ACCES_TOKEN = "token";
            const FETCH_URL = `${BASE_URL}${ACCES_TOKEN}/${this.state.latitude},${this.state.longitude}?lang=nl&units=si`;

            fetch(FETCH_URL, {
                method: "GET",
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    const data = json;
                    this.setState({
                        weather: data,
                        loader: false,
                        secondLoader: false
                    });
                })
        })
};
```

Comment: When do you save the query in localStorage? Remember that setState is async, meaning you cannot expect the state to be updated immediately after calling setState().

Comment: I save the query in `getLocation` function. Because setState is async I had to add a callback to trigger the `search` function. Is that maybe the problem it renders it again?

Comment: Can you also update the question with `handleChange` and `getLocation` code?

Comment: @DanielAndrei added `getLocation and` `showPosition`. The handleChange is just `query: event.target.value`

Comment: Edit: Updated with answer

Comment: WOW.................. this hurts. It works thank you so much!

Comment: I've rolled back your question to revision 2. Please don't delete the entire contents of your question, it could be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a type attribute to your button. I believe the reason why it's refreshing is that it has a default type of `submit`. Try using `type="button"` More info [here](http://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-button-type).